# Property 'srcObject' doesn't exist on reactive MediaStream object

Tags: vue.js, electron, vite

I'm currently trying to access to my webcam in an electron / vuejs / vitejs app, everything is seems to working well (I can access to my webcam in the app) but vs code JS is complaining about "Property 'srcObject' does not exist on type '{ readonly active: boolean; readonly id: string; onaddtrack: ((this: MediaStream, ev: MediaStreamTrackEvent) => any) | null; onremovetrack: ((this: MediaStream, ev: MediaStreamTrackEvent) => any) | null; ... 9 more ...; dispatchEvent: (event: Event) => boolean; }'."

Do you have any clue on how I can fix that ?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref, watch, reactive } from 'vue'

interface Device {
  deviceId: string;
  label: string;
  kind: string
}

let vid = reactive<MediaStream>(new MediaStream);

let deviceID = ref('');
let videoDevices = reactive<Device[]>([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  //Get all mediaDevices attached to the computer
  let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

  //Iterate over all of the devices
  for (let index = 0; index < devices.length; index++) {
    const device = devices[index];
    if (device.kind == "videoinput") {
      //Add the video device because it is a videoDevice. Manually create a new object with device details instead of passing device.
      videoDevices.push({
        deviceId: device.deviceId,
        kind: device.kind,
        label: device.label,
      });
    }
  }
  if (videoDevices && videoDevices.length > 0) {
    deviceID.value = videoDevices[0].deviceId
    console.log(devices[0].label)
  }
});

watch(deviceID,  async (newDeviceId, oldDeviceId) => {
  //Start the video with the exact deviceId we are trying to observe
  var constraints = {
    deviceId: { exact: newDeviceId },
  };

  //Create a stream with the webcam selected by the constraints above.
  let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: constraints,
  });

  //Set the source to be the stream we are capturing above
  vid.srcObject = stream;
 
  //When the stream is loaded, begin playing the stream
  vid.onloadedmetadata = async function() {
    const err = await  vid.play();
    console.log(err);
  };
});
</script>

<template>
  <video ref="vid" />
  <select v-model="deviceID" v-if="videoDevices && videoDevices.length >= 1" style="border:1px black solid">
    <option v-for="i in videoDevices" :key="i.deviceId" :value="i.deviceId" :selected="(deviceID == i.deviceId)">
        {{ i.label }}
    </option>
  </select>  
</template>

<style scoped>
.read-the-docs {
  color: #888;
}
</style>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is from TypeScript doing it's job of enforcing types. You've declared `vid` as a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) object.

```js
let vid = reactive<MediaStream>(new MediaStream);
```

MediaStream has no documented `srcObject` property, hence the error. Actually, `srcObject` is itself the MediaStream object. It looks like you should've defined `vid` as an [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement). This type matches all the properties and functions seen in your code.

Update your `vid` initialization code to:

```js
const vid = reactive<HTMLVideoElement>(new HTMLVideoElement())
```

Also, please update the `let` to `const` for all your `reactive` and `ref` variables since these are reactive objects and are not meant to be reassigned (only their inner values change in accordance with [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals)).